# Reporting Services - aligning Layout direction Tablix dynamic

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

Deal All,

Is there a way to have same report show in both layout direction based on parameter?
I have two data set one for label and one for data based on specific parameter show the labels
needed and the data needed but i am unable to switch the lay out direction it keeps LTR.
I need if anyone have an idea to change the layout direction from parameter.
I am having 50 reports and i don't like to have 150 reports because i am having 3 language.
I don't need to change the design of reports if there a new adding columns or changing columns.
I did it in data base by sending paramater name of the report and then get the dataset for it and then use the parameter of language to get label and data.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I dont know if this helps, because I have no experience with RTL, however if you select a TextBox and open the properties via F4, you can select for the text direction not only LTR or RTL but also an expression. Maybe this gives you the flexibility, you are looking for?

[image]

Comment: Hello My friend,
the problem is , i am having Arabic title as example Project name it will start as first columns from left in English version but in Arabic version  it should be placed last in columns or first from right, the alignment wont help me.
thank u for ur responce

Comment: I'm sorry that it has not helped.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I have been looking for

Answer (score 1):

Please right click on the report and choose view code  or press F7 and insert below code for the field:

```
<Style>
     <FontFamily />
     <TextAlign>Right</TextAlign>
</Style>
```

and

```
<Direction>RTL</Direction>
```